# How to get captions to appear when wrapping 2 environments into one using the `subtable` environment?

Tags: tables, captions, subcaption

I have a MWE below which is intended to wrap 2 environments into the table environment using `subtable`.  The first is a regular table created using `tabular`.  The other is an array.  It mostly works as expected, except for the fact that the captions do not appear.  This isn't usually a problem - what do I need to change to allow the captions to show up?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{table} %[b]  
\begin{subtable}[t]{5.48\textwidth} 
\caption{table1} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} ll >{$}l<{$} lll @{}} 
\toprule 
x & r & $t$  & $l$ & mycol  \\ \midrule 
2 & \{0,3,2,0\}   & $234$ & $77$ &  $2$  \\  
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{subtable} 
\begin{subtable}[t]{5.48\textwidth} 
\caption{table2} 
$\begin{array}{*{4}{c|}} 
\mc{} & \mc{A} & \mc{B} & \mc{C} \\ \cline{2-4} 
A     & 0      & 5    & 5   \\ \cline{2-4} 
D     & 1  &2   & 2  \\ \cline{2-4} 
\end{array}$ 
\end{subtable} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also tried things like changing `[t]` to `[b]`, etc., but that did not seem to change anything.

Comment: Please post something we can compile. Your class defines the starting point for this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked each subtable to be almost 5 and a half times your total `\textwidth`. Since the captions are centred, they don't appear on the page. (But you are doubtless getting warnings about overfull boxes.)

Change both occurrences of `5.48\textwidth` to something sensible such as `.48\textwidth` and the captions appear fine.

[image: subtables with captions]

You probably want to add `\centering` in each `subtable` environment.

Comment: I see thank you.  I didn't realize that the `\textwidth` was affecting the captions.  I thought they were separate.

Comment: @underdog987 It's just that they are centred relative to the `subtable` width. So if you make the `subtable` a mile wide, your subcaptions will be half a mile away. If you had left-aligned captions, it wouldn't affect them (but it would cause other problems). If `5.48` wasn't a typo, you probably want to rethink how to do whatever that was intended to do. (I was assuming it was a typo and got copy-pasted and so duplicated.)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Package `subcaption` version 3.1 or newest support `subfig` package syntax for including of subfigures. Using it your sub table will have their natural width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[position=top]{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb] %[b]
    \centering
\subfloat[table1]%
{
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} ll >{$}l<{$} lll @{}}
    \toprule
x & r           & $t$   & $l$   & mycol     \\ 
    \midrule
2 & \{0,3,2,0\} & $234$ & $77$  &  $2$      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\hfil
\subfloat[table 2]%
{
$\begin{array}{*{4}{c|}}
\mc{} & \mc{A} & \mc{B} & \mc{C} \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
A     & 0      & 5    & 5   \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
D     & 1  &2   & 2  \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
\end{array}$
}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```